Online preview display of answers/questions works only in the first round of editing in MSE
It seems I am experiencing a bug when working in MSE for some weeks. When I edit my answers/questions for the second time, the online displayer does not work on any devices (i.e., I cannot see any preview of the changes before confirming the edit). I don't have this problem in meta or CV, or when I type my answer/questions for the first time in MSE.
How can this be fixed?
PS: I asked this question also in an SE chatroom on latex, and the members advised me to post it in the relevant local meta site.


There are some posts which seem related - but since those posts are old, maybe the answers are no longer relevant: Answer preview in MSE not appearing and I'm not getting a "preview" of my answers on math.se (main), but am able to do so on meta?

@MartinSleziak thanks for the links! I just read the answers, but they do not address my case. On any device, only MSE does not work after posting. Even here in meta on my phone everything is okay.

Screenshots would be helpful as well as knowing what browser(s) you are using on your devices. Can you replicate this on any other SE site?

Click the "show preview" button. That should clear it up.
